# Pentium Assembly Code Question

Tags: assembly

I am new to Pentium assembly programming.

Could you check if I am doing the translation of C to assembly correctly?

**Condition: 32-bit addresses, 32 bit integers and 16 bit characters.**

char[5] vowels="aeiou";

Translate: vowels db "aeoiu" ; or should it be "vowels dw "aeoiu" ?

How to access vowels[p]? Is it byte[vowels+p*2]? (since characters are 16 bit? )

Many thanks

Comment: You are interested in MASM/NASM syntax, right?

Comment: … and what options have you specified to what assembler to make the characters 16 bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Intel assembly syntax is a little byte rusty, but `word[vowels+p*2]` is certainly more correct than `byte[vowels+p*2]`. You have to multiply by the size of the elements yourself *and* specify the kind of data read (here, 16-bit quantities).

For the first question, it depends how your assembler interprets `""` after `db` and `dw`. I do not know about that — I never mixed assembly and 16-bit encodings — but I would assume `dw` is correct.

Speaking of which, remember to use instruction `MOVZX` instead of the 16-bit registers that the assembler may let you use. Using the 16-bit registers in 32-bit mode generates long instructions that also execute slowly for a variety of reasons. `MOVZX` expands the 16-bit value read to occupy an entire 32-bit register, which is the correct way to handle them.

Comment: If I do "vowels dw "aeoiu" in the beginning. 
When I want to express : vowels[p], should I use word[vowels+p*4] instead of word[vowels+p*2]?  Since I declared each char in vowels as a word(16 bit).

Comment: I think that the "word" in `word[vowels+p*2]` only serves to specify what kind of quantity you want to be read, regardless of the computation of the address, which you must do yourself and where `vowels+p*2` is correct since each of your chars is 16-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `n`th element of an array of type `T` starting at `arr` is located at memory address `arr+n*sizeof(T)`.

Comment: "vowels dw "aeoiu" or vowels db "aeoiu"? 
Which one is correct?